# Why is asking for the right google translation considered a good question?

Tags: discussion, translation, specific-question, questions

The question [How to say I'm going out to buy myself something](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/56838/how-to-say-im-going-out-to-buy-myself-something) received 3 upvotes (Effective 23/03). While OP has at least provided google translation effort, OP has not clarified what he thinks is right/wrong and why. Judging by this, a lot of the other closed questions should have been answered. Why is this a good question?